# Plotting Count (colormap) in R

Tags: r, plot, markov-chains, colormap

I have a 200 by 200 matrix in R. Each column represents a future state (1-200), each row represents a current state (1-200). Within the matrix is the likelihood of going from given current state (row) to given future state (column).

I would like to visualize this using a graph, I was suggested using 
       image() 
function in R however the scales are highly incorrect and when I attempt to change them the entire "color map" changes too.

Ideally, id like to use color to demonstrate most likely transition (dark color) and have it gradient through to less likely transition (light color).

Could anybody point me in the fight direction?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html

Comment: that was very helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Did you completely solve the problem or need some help?